# Ties for Chords

Tags: notation, chords, sheet-music, ties

Are the chords should be always tied like this? Or there are rules when the ties should connect top/bottom of note heads in chords?

[image: two-note chord with both notes tied]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All notes within a chord should be tied, provided that all notes are intended to be held.

In the notation given in the question, both notes would be held for the length of two quarter notes.

In a case where only one note is held and the other is re-played, separate stems are used, as shown below.

[image: two-note chord with lower note tied and upper note repeated]

[image: two-note chord with upper note tied and lower note repeated]

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of tied-iness, those tie marks are pretty well as you describe. Top notes an upside down smile, bottom notes a smile. Reference Elaine Gould.

However, why you'd tie two crotchets in a bar, where a minim would do, I don't know!

Comment: I am just developing an app, so it's a abstract example, durations don't matter, it's just general question on how ties visually should connect chords